# Can I sync an Android phone with Lotus Notes Contacts and Calendar?

Tags: sync, android, lotus-notes

In my office, they currently use Windows Mobile phones, mostly for legacy reasons. Contacts and calendar are synced from Lotus Notes like this:

> Lotus Server → Lotus Notes → Lotus EasySync → Microsoft Outlook → Windows Mobile phone

Now, they're planning on switching to Android devices. Is there any way to do the following?

> Lotus Server → Lotus Notes → `what is missing?` → Android phone

I am therefore looking for any Windows application that would fetch Calendar and Contacts from Lotus Notes and allow the Android phone to sync with them.

---

Here are the details:

- Only contacts and calendar need to be synced, **no mails**.
- There's no need for "live" or "push" synchronization, only manual synchronization on the desktop
- The Domino server is some version 8, as well as Lotus Notes.
- There are only Windows machines.
- There is no way to install Lotus Notes Traveler on the server, which means I can't use any direct connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CompanionLink](http://www.companionlink.com/android/lotusnotes/) will sync Lotus Notes calendar, contacts, and to-dos with Android.

According to the site, you can sync by direct USB cable, local wi-fi, via Google, or through their hosted wireless product.

You also need to have DejaOffice on your device, which is free in the [Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.companionlink.clusbsync).

Comment: So am I correct that this thing doesn't use the default Android calendar or contacts, but rather rolls its own apps? I'll give it a shot the next time I can.

Comment: I have no idea. It's just what I was able to find with a quick search. (More than one forum post referenced it.)

Answer (score 0):

The 'what is missing' is your server admins installing Notes Traveler on the server. [Link](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/notes/traveler.html)

Is there a specific reason you guys aren't able to install it, beyond wanting to bypass the support team?

Comment: Traveler seems to require a higher version of Windows server than the one currently running. The update would involve more work and time than they could afford, I guess.

Comment: A lot of the 3rd party solutions are going to end up synching the data to the user's google account and then into their device.  This is a major security concern even if you trust google. Not to mention that doing a 2 way sync to a device using a 3rd party product almost always causes corrupt calendar items beyond what you'd normally see, resulting in a lot of helpdesk costs to fix.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the system requirements for traveler aren't any different than those for domino, which they obviously meet.